# How to get multiple selected values of select box in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a html form which has a select list box from which you can select multiple values because its multiple property is set to multiple. Consider form method is 'POST' but i have this error:

> (Array to string conversion)

The html code for the form is as follows:

```
<body>
<form action="{{route('info.create')}}" method="post">
  <select name="ary[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Option 1"> Option 1 </option>
    <option value="Option 2"> Option 2 </option>
    <option value="Option 3"> Option 3 </option>
    <option value="Option 4"> Option 4 </option>
    <option value="Option 5"> Option 5 </option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

I want to post the selected values in select list box on info.create page. So how i do to fix this error please?

My controller code is :

```
$info=new Info();
$info->Risques=$request['ary'];
```

Comment: you need to loop through.

Comment: share your controller code. you are getting error there. probably you are assigning array to a column.

Comment: You didn't show us the code that causes the error, but wherever you're using the output, you need to loop over the array you have and output every element individually. PHP can't know how to represent your array as a string.

Comment: my controller code     $info->Risques=$request['ary'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a typecasting issue in the Model upon calling the `create` method or Eloquent.

You need to add a variation of the following to your model:

```
    /**
     * Typecast for protection.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'ary' => 'array',  // ary being your column name
    ];
```

And if you want to see what the request is sending in your method in your controller you can do

```
$data = $request->all();
dd($data);
```

That is assuming your method is using the Request class `Request $request`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a laravel dev, but you'll need to loop through the select list as

```
if(!empty($_POST['ary'])){
    foreach($_POST['ary'] as $value){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

do a `dd($_POST['ary'])` #to see what it outputs